# Schwarz symmetrizaton and rank one symmetric spaces

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, real-analysis

does the symmetrization argument (Schwarz symmetrizaton ) works well in the setting of all   non compact symmetric spaces of rank one?

Comment: According to this reference https://shorturl.at/CGIJ3 by Harman, Howe and Morgan, the argument works for certain warped products, and this should include the case of hyperbolic space. I'm not sure if the remaining examples are warped products, but they are Riemannian submersions with one-dimensional base. 

It would certainly help if you made your question more precise.